# Throw Exception from Optional.ifPresent() Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am trying to throw the exception from Optional ifPresent() method of the Optional API in Java 8. I am checking if there is object present, if present then check that it's contain specific value i.e contain status Pending. If yes then throw exception otherwise return object and also throw exception if optional is empty i.e. dbUser is empty then thorw exception no user found

Here is my code:

```
Optional<User> dbUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

logger.info("Fetched user : " + dbUser + " by " + email);

logger.info("Fetched user status : " + dbUser.get().getStatus());

if (dbUser.isPresent()) {
    if (dbUser.get().getStatus().equals(Status.PENDING)) {
        throw new UserException("pending", email);
    }
}
```

The above code works fine but is this approach fine?

Comment: What do you want to do otherwise?

Comment: What if the status is something other than pending? What you want to do with that situation?

Comment: if status is other than pending then i will return dbUser

Comment: @im5an and what would you return is the `dbUser` itself is not present? Unless you share the complete implementation, it's tough to validate its correctness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Java 8 form could be:

```
if (dbUser.map(User::getStatus)
          .filter(Status.PENDING::equals)
          .isPresent()) {
    throw new UserException("pending", email);
}
```

Comment: you can replace the `if` statement with `filter(...).ifPresent(status -> {throw new ...;})`

Comment: how do you then plan to [return a `dbUser`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499106/throw-exception-from-optional-ifpresent-java-8#comment105172642_59499106) effectively?

Comment: And how will i handle if status os active not pending. If status is pending then i will throws exception but if status is active then i want to return dbUser

Comment: @CostiCiudatu yes but only if the exception is subclass of `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the very same code rewritten in Java-8 compliant [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
User dbUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email)                     // Optional<User>
                            .filter(u -> !Status.PENDING.equals(u)) // Optional<User>
                            .orElseThrow(() ->                      // User or UserException
                                 new UserException("pending", email));
```

Note following:

- The logged statement `dbUser.get().getStatus()` might throw [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--).
- I'd rather log the result at all:

  ```
  User dbUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                              .filter(u -> !Status.PENDING.equals(u))
                              .orElseThrow(() -> {
                                  logger.warn("Fetched user is pending: " + email);
                                  return new UserException("pending", email)
                              });

  logger.info("Fetched user=" + dbUser.getId() + ", status=" + dbUser.getStatus());
  ```

Comment: `User dbUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email).map(User::getStatus) ` shouldn't really work with that `map`ping.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have fixed that. Thanks

Comment: And how will i handle if status is active not pending.Fpr example If status is pending then i will throws exception but if status is active then i want to return dbUser

Comment: @im5an: This was not specified at your question. Please edit it first. Moreover, if you check my answer carefully, the exception is thrown only in case the status is `PENDING` and let other statuses to return the `User`.

Comment: @Nikolas: i edit my question

Answer (score 1):

this one just checks if a status is pending and throws the exception

```
userRepository.findByEmail(email).filter(u -> u.getStatus().equals(Status.PENDING))
                .ifPresent(u -> {
                    throw new UserException("pending", email);
                });
```

if you want to return a user but also throw exception if status is pending

```
User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).filter(u -> !u.getStatus().equals(Status.PENDING))
.orElseThrow(() -> new UserException("pending", email));
```

Comment: And how will i handle if status is active not pending.For example If status is pending then i will throws exception but if status is active then i want to return dbUser

Answer (score 0):

Sure, maybe just add:

```
if (dbUser.isPresent() && dbUser.get().getStatus() != null ) {
     if (dbUser.get().getStatus().equals(Status.PENDING)) {
          throw new UserException("pending", email);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An exception should normally be reserved for exceptional circumstances and it seems like the user having a pending status is a regular occurrence so I would prefer to return an optional value (assuming you are in a function that returns something, you didn't state the enclosing function). However depending on the context your way could also be acceptable.

Also, if you throw an exception for the pending state you should probably also throw one for a not existing user and for a user not having a state if that is possible, however I assume you didn't state this for brevity and to concentrate on the matter at hand.

Answer (score 0):

User does not exist, do you need to throw an exception？
Can use google's guava package;

```
   User dbUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
   Preconditions.checkNotNull(dbUser, "user not exists!"); 
   logger.info("Fetched user : " + dbUser + " by " + email);
   logger.info("Fetched user status : " + dbUser.get().getStatus());
   Precondtions.checkArgument(!Status.PENDING.equals(dbUser.getStatus()), "user status is pending");
```

Comment: i need to throw exception if user status is pending

Comment: @im5an, i've updated the answer ;   checkArgument will throw IllegalArgumentException if user status is pending